# Java: How to get upload and download speed

Tags: java, streaming, performance

I write a program to upload and download files to FTP server but I can not monitor the speed and the transfer rate.
I used FTPClient class and its two methods `retrievFile()` and `storeFile()`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
public class ReportingOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    public static final String BYTES_PROP = "Bytes";
    private FileOutputStream fileStream;
    private long byteCount = 0L;
    private long lastByteCount = 0L;
    private long updateInterval = 1L << 10;
    private long nextReport = updateInterval;
    private PropertyChangeSupport changer = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public ReportingOutputStream(File f) throws IOException {
        fileStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    }

    public void setUpdateInterval(long bytes) {
        updateInterval = bytes;
        nextReport = updateInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = { (byte) (b & 0xFF) };
        write(bytes, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        fileStream.write(b, off, len);
        byteCount += len;
        if (byteCount > nextReport) {
            changer.firePropertyChange( BYTES_PROP, lastByteCount, byteCount);
            lastByteCount = byteCount;
            nextReport += updateInterval;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (fileStream != null) {
            fileStream.close();
            fileStream = null;
        }
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changer.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changer.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }
}
```

After creating the stream, add a property change listener for `BYTES_PROP`. By default it fires the handler for every 1 KB received. Call `setUpdateInterval` to change.

Answer (score 0):

Since `retrieveFile` and `storeFile` deal with input and output streams, is it possible for you to write your own subclasses that can monitor the number of bytes transferred in or out over a certain time?