# I want to use java to calcuate the speed of network,but i don't known how to do

Tags: java, io, network-programming

I thought of using download files to calculator the speed, but it turns out to be unsuccessful. Operation is as follows：

I download a file and read every second file size, and use a small tool observation network speed at the same time. Finally found that the size of the file every second increase less (300 KB/S), but the tools it show JVM download speeds up to 4M/S.

Now I do not have a few thoughts,  and I need your help.

Comment: Similar questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322767/measuring-download-speed-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140101/java-how-to-get-upload-and-download-speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looking at the amount of actual data you are usually measuring in bytes (8 bits) and is without TCP/IP headers (can be 54 bytes).  When you are looking at the raw connection you are measuring in bits and including headers.  If the packets are fairly small (ie with a significant header overhead), you can have a 4 Mb/s (b for bit) connection and only 300 kB (B for byte or octet) of actual data.

Comment: Thank you very much, your question is very reasonable